# Need assistance with Powershell scripting for exchange 2010

Tags: powershell, exchange-server

Currently I am working on trying to create a powershell script that will allow different admins to be able to search,log and remove emails with Wildcards present. I am not knowledgeable in powershell or exchange but it is a function we greatly need.

```
#Param is requesting the input from the tech for required information
param (
    [String]$sent = $(Read-Host "Sent Date or Range. Use 12/11/2019..12/12/2019 for range"),
    [String]$From = $(Read-Host "From: Full Email address"),
    [String]$Subject = $(Read-Host "Subject")
    )
#UserCredential is used in order to gain functions to complete 
$UserCredential = Get-Credential
#This creates a new session for Powershell connecting to exchange. Exchange tools are not required to be installed on local machine.
$Session = New-PSSession -ConfigurationName Microsoft.Exchange -ConnectionUri http://Mailserver/PowerShell/ -Authentication Kerberos -Credential $UserCredential
Import-PSSession $Session -DisableNameChecking
#This is the command to get the needed information and where to display the results.
Get-Mailbox -ResultSize unlimited -server mail | Search-Mailbox -SearchQuery Sent:$sent,From:"$From",Subject:"$Subject" -TargetMailbox mailbox -TargetFolder SearchResult -LogOnly -LogLevel Full
#This removes the Powershell connection to prevent un-needed connections requiring them to Timeout to close.
Remove-PSSession $Session
```

If i put in a full email address with subject and date it works. But if I need to put a wildcard infront of domain address in "From" or "subject" i get the error "Suffix matching isn't supported. Please remove the prefix '*' or type another query"

Also I have an issue with running the local installed tools vs the one on the server. I have exchange management tools installed so when I run this portion of code it fails with unrecognized cmdlet in this script but works if I am just pulling user statistics.

But from my understanding these options should give me the same results. This code would replace the lines $session and import-pssession above.

```
. 'C:\Program Files\Microsoft\Exchange Server\V14\bin\RemoteExchange.ps1'
Connect-ExchangeServer -auto
```

Error for local session:

> Search-Mailbox : The term 'Search-Mailbox' is >not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, >function, script file, or operable program. Check >the spelling of the name, or if a path was >included, verify that the path is correct and 
>   try again.
>   At D:\scripts\ps1\Exchange\Exchange-User->Folder-Remove.ps1:19 char:50
>   + ... t-Mailbox -ResultSize unlimited -server mail | >Search-Mailbox -Search ...

Comment: If you're on Exchange 2010, what OS platform are you on?  client and server?  Version of Powershell?  $PSVersionTable

Comment: Windows 10- PSversion 5.1.17763.771
Server 2012R2 PSVersion 4.0